# How to store one value in application in android?

Tags: android

I am making one application in which one integer value as a score.

I want to show that last result value when i restart the application and press on score button which is on home page.

**score.java**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Timer = intent.getStringExtra("Timer_Value");
String totalQue = intent.getStringExtra("totalQue");
String right = intent.getStringExtra("right");      

String result = "Taken time for this Task :"+Timer+" \n"+ "Your score is "+right+"/"+totalQue;

TextView results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
results.setText(result);

Button main_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Mainmenu);
main_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Score.this.finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(Score.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the official android documentation and tutorials.

Comment: you can use sharedPreference for storage.

Comment: Please search/follow the tutorials before ask this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save your score in sharedprefrences.

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void LoadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String score = sharedPreferences.getString("SCORE", "");

}
```

To save your score simply call SavePreferences("SCORE", "YOUR_SCORE");
And to retreive it call the LoadPreferences().

Comment: It will override last value everytime?

Comment: Yes if you want to keep a recored for all the scores you must use database.

Comment: @Zeel R u success with Databse or not?

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes. I used shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Youc can store small data in it.

```
// To save data
SharedPreferences.Editor gameScore = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
gameScore.putInt("score", 30).commit();;

// To read saved data
SharedPreferences gamePrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
int gameScore = gamePrefs.getString("score", 0); // here zero will be returned when there is nothign to return
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared Preference for store the value. Shared Preference stores your value until user uninstall the application or you clear your shared preference variable.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("score", 3);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
int score = prefs.getString("score", 0);   // Here zero is default value return when there is no value in shared preference.
```